# deleting an image from file system node.js

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I have the following route for uploading profile images. Each user can have only one profile image, so as the new image is uploaded I want to delete the old image from the file system and mongo db. So far I have been attempting to delete the file from the file system using fs.unlink. Following is the code for my post route:

```
app.post('/upload', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {

    uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, './public/uploads/');
    let oldFileName = '';

    Image.findOne({ member_id: req.user.member_id })
        .then(oldImage => {
            oldFileName = oldImage.imageName;

            console.log(uploadDir + oldFileName);
            fs.unlink(uploadDir + oldFileName, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });


    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render('index', {
                msg: err
            });
        } else {

            const newImage = {
                imageName: req.file.filename,
                image_caption: req.body.image_caption,
                member_id: req.user.member_id
            }
            new Image(newImage)
                .save()
                .then(image => {

                    req.flash('success_msg', 'Image added');
                    res.redirect('/');
                })
                .then(resize => {
                    let imgHeight = 150;
                    let imgWidth = 150;
                    sharp(req.file.path)
                        .blur(.3)
                        .toFile('public/thumbs/blurred_' + req.file.originalname, function (err) {
                            if (!err) {
                                req.flash('success_msg', 'Thumbnail created');
                                //res.redirect('/');
                            }
                        });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });


        }
    });
});
```

The problem I am facing is:

- How to handle the situation where the user is uploading for the first
  time and does not have any old images.
  when I try to delete I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageName' of null
    at Image.findOne.then.oldImage (C:\Users\Amin Baig\Desktop\Projects\photogallery2\app.js:130:36)

Also, it tells me that it cannot find the file although I can see the path and file in the error.

```
{ Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Users\Amin Baig\Desktop\Projects\photogallery2\public\uploads\I7SN7PAEl_1531803568428_dont_judge_me-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg'
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Amin Baig\\Desktop\\Projects\\photogallery2\\public\\uploads\\I7SN7PAEl_1531803568428_dont_judge_me-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg' }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn’t have a file yet, couldn’t you use an if statement that contains a Mongo query to check if the profile picture’s existence is “true” or false?

Answer (score 0):

> How to handle the situation where the user is uploading for the first time and does not have any old images. when I try to delete I get the following error:

You can use [`fs.existsSync(path)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) to check whether a path exists or not

> Returns true if the path exists, false otherwise.

```
'use strict';

let fs = require('fs');

let fileNameWithPath = uploadDir + oldFileName;
console.log(fileNameWithPath);

if (fs.existsSync(fileNameWithPath)) {
  fs.unlink(uploadDir + oldFileName, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```